# Paremetric surface revolved around y-axis

Tags: calculus, surfaces, parametric, area

if I'm finding the area of the surface generated by revolving the curve around the y-axis I use the equation $2\pi x\sqrt{(x')^2+(y')^2}$ and I'm given $$x=(2/3)t^{3/2}$$ $$y=2\sqrt{2}$$ and I got this was derivatives $$x'=t^{1/2};y'=t^{-1/2}$$ that gives me $$(2\pi(2/3)t^{3/2})\sqrt{ ((t^{-1/2})^2)+t }$$ then I u sub gives.. $$\pi(2/3)u^{3/2}$$I go from $$0<t<\sqrt{3}$$ I get a negative number. what am I doing wrong?
du is 2x =$$2(2/3)t^{3/2}$$ right
$$u= (t^{-1/2})^2)+t $$

Comment: I have attempted to place your question into Latex to give it a good math format. Please examine the question and make sure that this is what you were trying to ask.

Comment: I just fixed it

Comment: You seem to be using x and t interchangeably. What is your u substitution?

Comment: du=$$2(2/3)t^{3/2}$$   because $$2\pi(2/3)t^{3/2}$$ without the $$\pi$$ is du

Comment: So u = 2(2/3)(2/5)$t^{\frac{5}{2}}$? That is what your du would yield as u. Or, do you mean u = what you have above?

Comment: how why...but DU is supposed to be what's on the outside or I can't integrate. $$u=(t+(t^{-1/2}^{2})$$ I edited it again

Comment: There are many ways to choose a u substitution. Taking what is inside the square root is not the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified version of the integral you need to find. All I have done is write things like $(t^{-1/2})^2 = t^{-1}$ as $\frac{1}{t}$. I am omitting the constant out in front as well. Multiply by it at the end.

$\int_0^{\sqrt{3}} t^{3/2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{t}+t} dt.$
Consider letting $u = t^2$. Then $du = 2t$. This is not the most intuitive $u$ substitution, but it makes things much cleaner.

Looking at just the pieces of the integrand: $t^{3/2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{t}+t} = t\sqrt{t}\sqrt{\frac{1}{t}+t} = t\sqrt{t(\frac{1}{t}+t)} = t\sqrt{1+t^2}$.

We then make the u substitution. Since $du = 2t dt$, we divide by 2. The $t$ outside the square root is taken care of by replacing $t~dt$ with $du$.

We are left with the integral $\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int \sqrt{u + 1}~ du = \dfrac{1}{3}(u + 1)^{3/2}.$

So, back substituting yields $\dfrac{1}{3} (t^2+1)^{3/2}.$

Evaluating at 0 to $\sqrt 3$ gives $\dfrac{1}{3} (3+1)^{3/2} - \dfrac{1}{3} (1)^{3/2} = \dfrac{7}{3}.$

Multiplying by our previous constant 2π(2/3), we get $\dfrac{28\pi}{9}$.

Comment: how did the u sub of t^2 yield u+1 I see how you have 1 but why is 1/t=u? understand why you had to find away to get a constant under the radical so you don't have a negative answer though.

Comment: I have edited the answer to give more detail. I just used basic algebra to manipulate the integrand into a nicer format for the substitution.

Comment: okay I get it but this seems odd that you would have to make that sort of u sub and break up the $$t^{3/2}$$